# Once There Were Nine

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix took you to my infix, you see;
>
> My suffix is you wishing a relationship to be.
>
> I was once united by a piece of jewelry -
>
> What is the word that is me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My prefix took you to my infix, you see;

> To **fell** something is to bring it **low**.

My suffix is you wishing a relationship to be.

> To **ship** people (Internet slang) is to write that they have a relationship though they don't in the canonical text.

I was once united by a piece of jewelry -

> The **fellowship** of the ring was, and was nine people (explaining the title).

What is the word that is me?

> "Me" is thus **fellowship**.